# Problem during Qt 5.1 installation

Tags: software-installation, qt5

I downloaded the Qt 5.1.0 installation file for Linux, and trying to install gives me an error. It stops when copying these files:

```
/opt/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/Src/qtbase/tests/benchmarks/gui/image/qimagereader/images/font.bmp
/opt/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/Src/qtbase/tests/auto/gui/image/qimagereader/images/font.bmp
/opt/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/Src/qtbase/tests/auto/gui/image/qimagewriter/images/font.bmp
/opt/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/Src/qtbase/tests/auto/gui/image/qimage/images/image.bmp
```

Then it complains it can't find some other files, and the installation is aborted.

Installing in my home directory seemed to work fine though. What could be the problem?

Comment: This is not really answering your question, but why not simply use [Nokia's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~forumnokia/+archive/fn-ppa) to install the latest available Qt libraries?

Comment: @Sh3ljohn Nokia's PPA seems to be quite old. Latest update is from 64 weeks ago. I was also looking for a fast way to install Qt-5.1, with no luck so far. I've also found [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~beineri/+archive/opt-qt51) but its packages have some dependency problems with Raring.

Comment: It would help to know what other files it complains about. Please read: http://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-ask